# Angular 7 : Rxjs behaviour subject subscribe not working on page reload but works in route navigation

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

In my **header component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getUser((data)=>{
      this.authService.userInfo.next(data)

    })
}
```

In **authService.ts**

```
export class AuthService {

  userInfo= new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

}
```

In my another component I am subscribing the variable in `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.auth.userInfo.subscribe((data)=>{
      this.userInfo = data.user;
      console.log('user data subsribed ',this.userInfo)
    })  

}
```

This works fine on route navigations but when I reload the page the subscriber is not triggering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility that **`userInfo`** subject emitted before it be subscribed to. Which mean the subcribing component missed the data. I suggest to use [ReplaySubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/replaysubject.html) instead. It hold the data and late subcribing component will still get it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to subscribe to the subject in the ngAfterViewInit life cycle hook instead of ngOnInit

Answer (score 0):

You don't subscribe the this.authService.getUser() function. userInfo is subscribe but that one doesn't trigger the getUser() function.

From this example I don't know when it is working while navigation.

But aren't you making it too complex by introducing a behaviourSubject? Do you need this? If it's because you want to cache the result of the getUser call then you better add

```
getUser() => this.http.get<UserInfo>().pipe(share())
```

Or introduce a variable:

```
getUser() => this.userInfo ? of(this.userInfo) : this.http.get<UserInfo>().pipe(tap(userInfo => this.userInfo = userInfo))
```